# Using a while loop to update list with elements from another list and find the sum of new list

Tags: python, while-loop

I am having a hard time using a while loop to add a card to the list and keep updating the sum.
Currently I am getting an operand type error saying that I cannot add a list to a list. Ideally
every time the player chooses a new card with 'y' then the list would update and the score would update as well.

```
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]


def blackjack():
    should_continue = True
    player_card1 = int(random.choice(cards))
    comp_card = random.choice(cards)
    if input("Do you want to play? Type 'y' or 'n'\n") == 'y':
    
        while should_continue:
            
            add_card = int(random.choice(cards))
            player_cards = [player_card1]
            player_cards.append(add_card)
            comp_card = random.choice(cards)
            player_score = sum(player_cards)
            
            print(f"Your cards: {player_cards}, current score:{player_score}")
            print(f"Computer's first card: {comp_card}")
            if input(f"Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:") == 'y':
                player_card1 = player_cards
                comp_card = comp_card
            else:
                should_continue = False
                #calculate()

    else:
        should_continue = False

blackjack()
```

Comment: Because you're declaring `player_cards` inside your loop, it will get reassigned a value of `[player_card1]` on every iteration

Comment: Assigning `player_card1 = player_cards` in the inner `if` statement and `player_cards = [player_card1]` at the beginning of the next loop is causing you to generate nested lists from the previous rounds cards. I don't think player cards should be defined inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were creating nested lists. The cards were added like so

```
[10, 10]
[[10, 10], 10]
```

So, you can't `[10, 10] + 10`
I've fixed it and removed some dead code. Consider using something like PyCharm for debugging, syntax check and other benefits

```
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]


def blackjack():
    should_continue = True
    player_cards = [random.choice(cards)]
    if input("Do you want to play? Type 'y' or 'n'\n") == 'y':

        while should_continue:
            player_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
            comp_card = random.choice(cards)
            player_score = sum(player_cards)

            print(f"Your cards: {player_cards}, current score:{player_score}")
            print(f"Computer's first card: {comp_card}")
            if not input(f"Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:") == 'y':
                should_continue = False

blackjack()
```